# im trying to make a flexbox of 4 items (2 images and 2 texts next to them) but its seems there is a problem

Tags: css

so this is the html code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="flex-col-1">
            <div class="flex-left flex-item1"><img src="./images/berlin.avif" alt="berlin"></div>
            <div class="flex-left"><h2>Berlin</h2><p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p></div>
            <div class="flex-left flex-item2"><img src="./images/eric-ward-uD0W-swVGgE-unsplash.jpg" alt="Poland"></div>
            <div class="flex-left"><h2>Holand</h2><p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p></div>
        </div>
```

and this is the css

```
.flex-col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-left {
  /* margin: 5%; */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 500px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

why all the 4 items dont stay in a row?(forget : MUSIC...4 different places)
[image]
whats the best practise for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you need a text next to image and so the other in one row,
here what you need to do

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-col-1">
    <div class="flex-left flex-item1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/000000/" alt="berlin" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-left">
      <h2>Berlin</h2>
      <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
        the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point
        of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content
        here', making it look like readable English.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-left flex-item2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/000000/" alt="Poland" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-left">
      <h2>Holand</h2>
      <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
        the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point
        of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content
        here', making it look like readable English.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css will be

```
.flex-col-1 {
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex-col-1 div {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  img {
    border-radius: 8px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a `.col` and `.row` style element.
.col should have `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` whereas .row should have `flex-direction: row`

That helps a lot for structuring with flexbox.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder">
    <div>Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder">
    <div>Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Edit: (4 Elements all in a row)

To achieve the four Elements "img - text - img - text" all in one row you can simply delete the `flex-wrap: wrap;` from your `.flex-col-1`.
*(Or change it to `flex-wrap: nowrap;`)*

Read here more about [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).

Comment: but that doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Hmm... than I misunderstood your question.
Do you want to have "img - text - img - text" all in one row?

Comment: @NickGlav I edited my answer how to achieve that all 4 elements stay in a row

Comment: This is not right because it has no flexibility at all!

Comment: Then please clarify your question, what do you want to have as an end result?
For the current question "why all the 4 items don't stay in a row?" is the answer because you are using flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: yeah i want ALL 4 item to be in 1 row with flexbox but as you can see one only 3 takes

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to flex wrap (and 100x more predictable), you can group the image and text in a container, then use a media query to switch to column on smaller screens.

```css
.con {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .con {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, nam.</p>
</div>

<div class="con">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, nam.</p>
</div>

<div class="con">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, nam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i aware of this solution but i want 4 items in arow image-text -image-text